# Networking problems with new kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I am new to Ubuntu world since I've been using it for near a year or so. Software is great, but I have some hardware issues.

Along with Ubuntu 14.04 come kernel witch was ok – some minor issues : bluetooth and wireless were constantly turning on after reboot - fine. With Ubuntu 14.10 and kernel 3.16 things slightly improve on bluetooth side – good. With 3.18.8 things got back they wore -bad.
But then I installed kernel 3.19 and things got worse. Now my ethernet connection have problem. I can start it, load a page, then it turns off, then on.....
I can't use old kernel forever and newer kernels are worse than the old ones.

My laptop is Lenovo y580 with:
Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4).

How do I solve this problems, no software could help (blueman,windows wireless drivers, network tools)?
Can I download a single driver for each device if some of the issues come back with newer kernels?
Should I report this problems and where? I understand it's not an easy task.

Comment: What logs say? Take a look at `/var/log/` files and see what gets written and where. `ls -tl /var/log/ | less` should give you logs sorted from most recently touched down. Take few first and see what your system tells you. I'd go with `dmesg` and `syslog`, off my head. Oh, `dmesg` should output something too. In short: more data required. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I guess I wasn't clear in my question, sorry. Didn't understand really your answer. As I said I am a noob.  Is it possible to download/extract a single driver for my device from the working kernel eg: 3.16? This way I can use it later on some newer Ubuntu releases and implement it in some newer kernels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got the answer here:
[ALX on AR8191 does not appear to be working 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616182/alx-on-ar8191-does-not-appear-to-be-working-15-04).

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-2000-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz

UPDATE : A correction to suggested duplicate. I have mistaken and offered the wrong link.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).

Comment: It was one of my first questions and didn't know how this site is functioning. I have resolved it and don't believe it can help anyone further so I answered superficial just to close.