# ALX on AR8191 does not appear to be working 15.04

Tags: ethernet, 15.04

I am trying to use the ethernet port on my Lenovo y580, which previously worked untill I upgraded to ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10. My hardware is recognized, and I can connect to an ethernet network, however whenever I try to load a webpage the connection just stops working. I can observe this by pinging my router while connected via ethernet. Whenever I try to load the page, the ping command just freezes. This has been an issue ever since I upgraded to 15.04 Beta.

I believe this is an error with the alx driver based off of my research. My wireless card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR8161. Does anyone know a workaround, or have a verification of my issue?

EDIT: I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working/157604#157604), as recommended by one user, and it did not sucessfully compile. I believe that the user here was having a different issue, as he did not specify my issue.

Comment: *Can you try this tutorial steps may be it help* http://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working/157604#157604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761  this gives the work around

In the networking indicator select Edit Connections
On wired connection 1 change the MTU to 8192
Save this

Reboot working wired connection

Comment: Amazing - this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Same here...
worked perfectly in 14.04
then there were issues in 14.10 with virtual machines causing eth0 to stop working
now in 15.04 eth0 only works for a few seconds then stops.
if I restart

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
then the network comes back up for only a few seconds then stops again.
The driver is "alx"

$ lshw
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: b8:88:e3:8a:4b:01
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:d3600000-d363ffff ioport:2000(size=128)


$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     1917D292620190CB7319BDE
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        9E:64:80:70:92:F3:A6:A8:F6:6F:3B:7E:A4:CB:37:67:FD:FA:E0:8A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

The Driver hasn’t been worked on in some time
https://github.com/mcgrof/alx

Comment: Is there a bug report filed on launchpad, or can we file one? I do not know how to go about this process.